# IP Conflicts from mikrotik router for multiple ip addresses (that it isnt assigned)

Tags: networking, wireshark, mikrotik

I have a point to point wireless connection using two mikrotiks. When I plug the mikrotik into a switch with just my laptop I get an IP address conflict on my machine no matter what IP I am assigned. Using wireshark i see the conflicts are from the mac address of the mikrotik on the other end of the wireless connection. Why is it conflicting with multiple IP addresses when the router itself is assigned a single IP address with no NAT entries or anything like that? I included a little diagram to help visualize my issue

[me]
[mikrotik] --------------[problem mikrotik]----(other equipment on diff subnet)

The problem mikrotik has a wan on the same subnet as my machine. The lan is a different subnet. Any ideas? When I plug the equipment into my network I get IP conflicts on a lot of different servers. Took me forever to isolate it to this mikrotik! Thanks

Oh and all this equipment has been working previously with no known changes made to the configs. It just started acting up recently.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: What are the IP addresses of the 2 routers? Also is there a route in place, it could be corrupt.. Have you reset the router to your pc and reconfigured? If you can do it...

Comment: 192.168.1.100 for central router and 192.168.1.101 for problem router WAN and 10.0.0.1 for it's LAN. There are routes in place and they are the same as before the problems started happening. These mikrotiks have been working for literally years with this config and nothing appears to be changed. I've done some google searches and it appears this problem has occured for others and the only fix I've seen is to replace the router. I'm hoping serverfault can offer up some better suggestions! Thanks for your reply

Comment: many many times

Comment: It isn't doing arp spoofing, or something similar on the WAN interface is it?

Comment: You said no changes were made to the configs, but did anything else change? Your machine or other devices on the network?

Comment: Are you using PPoE or a cable modem as your WAN connection? If you plug a computer directly into the modem what IP do you grab? I know a lot of newer modems will try to hand out private DHCP and do a 1:1 NAT to whatever device it connects to instead of passing the public IP to the device.

Comment: Replacing the router does not sound right. If the problem is actually caused by one of the Mikrotik routers, then worst case scenario would be re-installing Mikrotik from scratch to resolve it. I find unlikely that a hardware issue would cause this kind of problem. Have you tried resetting your configuration and/or upgrading mikrotik to the latest version?

Comment: Is the point-to-point wireless connection acting as a bridge? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the ARP cache from all devices? If multiple devices shared the same IP address, that is recorded in the ARP cache of neighboring network devices. Til that is cleared, the devices will keep thinking there are duplicate addresses on the network

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the "IP Conflict" is caused by several configuration options of *problem mikrotik* interface that (over the wireless link) is bridged to *me*:

1. IP address (with proper subnet mask) belonging to *me*'s subnet is missing (this is the misconfiguration that should be fixed);
2. `proxy-arp` is enabled (this might be OK depending on the needs).

It is possible that the above mentioned interface is a bridge itself, then IP address, most likely, should be assigned to the bridge (and not any interfaces belonging to the bridge).

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the problematic Mikrotik does not have Hotspot functionality enabled? If it is enabled, probably your side of the point-to-point link is being part of the "client" hotspot feature.

Mikrotik does a lot of L2 and L3 "magic" to capture any wireless client that may connect and "capture" their traffic to enforce any hotspot authentication or restriction. It does that no matter the client IP configuration.